# Angular 6 Router doesnt navigate

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

i have a component(Unlock) which router.navigate doesnt work somehow. I couldnt figure out why router doesnt redirect the page. It only happens in this component. Any ideas ?

```
submit() {

    if (!this.unlockForm.valid) { return; }
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.userDataService.unlockCpo(this.model).subscribe(data => {
      this.oauthService.refreshToken().then(done => {
        this.translateService.get('UnlockAccount.UnlockSuccess').subscribe((res: string) => {
          this.toastr.success(res);
          this.isLoading = false;
         this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']); // there is not working but debuger goes on the line and no errors thrown..
        });
      }
```

And there my app.routing.ts

```
{
        path: 'unlock',
        component: UnlockComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'logout',
        component: LogoutComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [CloudConnectivityGuard, AccessGuard],
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
```

Here the canActive method

```
 canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    // const hasIdToken = this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken();
    const hasIdToken = true;
    const hasAccessToken = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();

    if (!hasIdToken || !hasAccessToken) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    if (!this.userService.isCpo()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/unlock']);
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.router.navigateByUrl('/unlock')` ?

Comment: yeah doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of the router as well in your guard.

Also if you return **true** it will navigate to the page.

```
constructor(protected router: Router) { }

canActivate() {
    const hasIdToken = true;
    const hasAccessToken = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();

    if (!hasIdToken || !hasAccessToken) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

    if (!this.userService.isCpo()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/unlock']);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry but after unlocking progress it never goes in that if condition.. directly goes to true.. Object of the router is there, just forgot to paste here..